# How to refresh content of tooltipster not using ajax

Tags: jquery, tooltipster, bootstrap-table

I am trying to refresh the content of tooltipster before every showing but it is not working every time.  Here is what my code looks like:

```
$('#harvesterTable').find('tr').each(function(i, el) {
                $(this).tooltipster({
                    content: $('#tooltipTable'),
                    functionBefore: function (origin, continueTooltip) {
                        continueTooltip();
                        $('#tooltipTable').bootstrapTable('removeAll');
                        $('#tooltipTable').bootstrapTable('refresh', { url: '/ReporterDataSource/FlowStatisticsWS.svc/GetRouterDataByHarvesterID?id=' + $tds.eq(0).text() });
                        $(".tooltipster-content").html($('#tooltipTable'));
                    }
                });
     });
```

As you can see from the code, before the tooltip is shown, I am updating the data-url for a bootstrap table so get data for the row or cell that is being hovered over.  I have tested updating the bootstrap table and it works correctly as I am doing it in other parts of my code.  The problem though is that tooltipster doesn't always show the new table data.

Any help would be great!  Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to run without content setting? Are you getting the correct data back on the ajax call? In the last line of functionBefore can you change the content with `this.content = `. Also what is bootstrapTable?

Comment: bootstrapTable is an open source very popular table ui framework: http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/docs/examples.html

I am getting the correct data back in the ajax call.  I did try to run without setting context with no luck/similar results.

I have tested out doing this bootstrap table refresh and it is working correctly.  Tooltipster seems to be continually caching the data incorrectly.